# how to solve webapp runner and poi-ooxml conflict

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-poi

I am getting this error in the code I wrote in sbt 1.7.1

```scala
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook
    new SXSSFWorkbook
  }
}
```

I have added such dependencies.

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"
organization := "com.example"

name := "Hello"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "5.2.2",
  "com.github.jsimone" % "webapp-runner" % "9.0.27.1" intransitive() 
    exclude("commons-io","commons-io")
)
```

there is such an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.byteArray(I)[B
at org.apache.commons.io.output.AbstractByteArrayOutputStream.needNewBuffer(AbstractByteArrayOutputStream.java:104)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.java:38)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.newPackage(XSSFWorkbook.java:513)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:230)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:226)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:214)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(SXSSFWorkbook.java:262)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(SXSSFWorkbook.java:232)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(SXSSFWorkbook.java:207)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(SXSSFWorkbook.java:182)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(SXSSFWorkbook.java:143)
at example.Hello$.main(Hello.scala:6)
at example.Hello.main(Hello.scala)
```

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```scala
// build.sbt
calaVersion := "2.13.6"
organization := "com.example"

name := "Hello"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "5.2.2",
  "com.github.jsimone" % "webapp-runner" % "9.0.27.1" % "provided",
)
```